# celery - pool_restart does not support adding new tasks well

Tags: python, celery

Recently, I have created a celery project, the whole project looks like this

```
proj
  |-- math
  |    |-- tasks.py (add)
  |
```

I started a worker with command **'celery -A proj worker -l info'**;

```
 -------------- celery@Jacky v3.1.15 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         XXXX:0x40706d8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5679//
- ** ---------- .> results:     mongodb://localhost:27017/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

And then added a new package named **text** [The latest code structure as following shown]

```
proj
  |-- math
  |     |-- tasks.py (add)
  |
  |-- text
  |     |-- tasks.py (scan)
```

At this time, I want to restart the worker by the following code

```
app.control.broadcast('pool_restart', {'modules': ['proj.math.tasks',
                                                   'proj.text.tasks']})
```

To check it, I ran **celery -A proj inspect registered**. And got the following result

```
-> celery@Jacky: OK
    * proj.math.tasks.add
    * proj.math.tasks.minus
    * proj.text.tasks.scan
```

The result indicates the task **scan** has been added successfully. After that, I tried to execute the new added task with the following code

```
result = app.send_task('proj.text.tasks.scan', args=('fjkdjfdfj.mp3',))
print result.get(timeout=1)
```

However, I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 361, in workloop
    result = (True, prepare_result(fun(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 349, in _fast_trace_task
    return _tasks[task].__trace__(uuid, args, kwargs, request)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\app\registry.py", line 27, in __missing__
    raise self.NotRegistered(key)
```

The **self** in line 27 is an object of type **celery.app.registry.TaskRegistry**. And I found there are more than one object of such type exist. That is, every child process within pool still maintain an instance of TaskRegistry'.

Why the result of **celery -A proj inspect registered** includes the 'scan', but I still get **NotRegistered' exception? Does it because the child process within pool do not sync with the main process.

Answer (score 0):

If the task is not registered in the current process, then you can use `send_task()` to call the task by name instead. But generally you use `delay` or `apply_async` instead because `send_task` calls task by name which may lead to [some errors](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports)

You can call your task as

```
tasks.scan.apply_async(args=['fjkdjfdfj.mp3',], timeout=1)
```

If you really want to call tasks with `send_task` only, name your workers which makes it calling tasks easier. So you task should look like

```
from celery import task
@task(name='my_named_task')
def scan(foo):
    #do something in background
```

Then you can call it using `send_task` without any problems.

```
app.send_task('my_named_task', args=('fjkdjfdfj.mp3',))
```

Comment: both using apply_async and renaming the task could not work in my side

Comment: Each work process within the pool maintains an instance of TaskRegistry. And the value is differ from the one in main process. Is it the root cause?